# Freemarker template string util that can create n number of characters or from a string?

Tags: freemarker

is there a string util can can do something like this

<#assign junk="repeatMe"/>
${string.utils.repeat(junk,2)}

OUTPUT:
repeatMerepeatMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<#assign junk = "repeatMe" />

<#list 0..1 as x>${junk}</#list>
```

Comment: If you want to specify the *number* of iterations, it's better to use `..<` operator instead, like `0..<repetations`.